# PHP csv upload works on mac but not windows

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I have a csv upload plugin for wordpress. I can upload the files on a mac but on a windows pc it fails to upload. The csv files are created on the pc with utf-8 encoding.

```
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {

if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['csv_file']['size'] > 0 && $_FILES['csv_file']['type'] === 'text/csv') {

        global $wpdb;

    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

    $start_row = (int) $_POST['start_row'];

    /*
     * Get CSV data and put it into an array
     */
    $fileData = file_get_contents($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name']);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $fileData);
    $csv = array();

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $csv[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    /*
     * Put each row into the database
     */
    $x = 1;
    $insert_count = 0;
    $insert_output = array();

    $wpdb->query('TRUNCATE TABLE table');

    foreach ($csv as $data) {

            if ($x >= $start_row) {

              $date = fix_date($data[0]);

              $sql = "
                INSERT INTO table ( date, column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6, column_7 ) 
                VALUES ( '" . $date . "', '" . addslashes( $data[1] ) . "', '" . utf8_encode( $data[2] ) . "', '" . addslashes( $data[3])  . "', '" . $data[4] . "', '" . addslashes( $data[5] ) . "', '" . $data[6] . "', '" . $data[7] . "' )
                ";

                $wpdb->query($sql)/* or die($sql)*/;
                $insert_output[] = $insert_count . '. Added: ' . $data[1] . ' - ' . $data[3] . '<br />';
                $insert_count++;

            }

            $x++;
        }

    echo '<div class="csv_success">Success. ' . number_format($insert_count) . ' rows uploaded.</div>';

} else {

    echo '<div class="csv_failure">Please make sure the file you uploaded is a CSV.</div>';

}

}
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work on windows and mac?

Cheers

Comment: PHP_EOL is the newline constant for the operating system you are using, however if the file was created on on OS and you're uploading it on the other, it may not work. Maybe try explode("\n",$x) and trimming the lines as \n should be in both.

Comment: checking for non-zero size is NOT a proper way to validate an upload. a failed upload can easily have non-zero size. you need to check `if($_FILES['csv_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` before you do ANYTHING else with the upload. And `PHP_EOL` is the **LOCAL** system's eol character. it's useless for handling cross-platform stuff, because a Mac eol is not a PC eol

Comment: just out of curiosity, have you checked the `error_log` file [sometimes] located in `public_html`?

Comment: btw this wasn't my code i'm trying to debug a previous developers code, looks like the $_FILES['csv_file']['type'] === 'text/csv' is the issue

Comment: What do you mean with Upload on Mac or Windows ? are you running the code in a WebServer running in Mac and another Server with Windows ? Or are you testing to upload (as a client, with a browser) in a Windows Machine and in Mac Machine.

Comment: $_FILES['csv_file']['type'] === 'text/csv' check is where the problem was the mime type was different for the same file on pc is application/vnd.ms-excel and on a mac it is text/csv, so i'm changing the if statement

Comment: Actually $_FILES['csv_file']['type'] === 'text/csv' sometime in windows type of csv will be 'application/octet-stream' so check that too

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die("not connect");

mysql_select_db("demo") or die("select db");

 function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
 }



  //Set path to CSV file
    $csvFile = 'page.csv';

 $csv = readCSV($csvFile);
 //echo count($csv);     
 for ($i=1; $i <count($csv) ; $i++) { 



    $sql="insert into demo1     (name,bdate,phonenumber ) values('".$csv[$i][0]."','".$csv[$i][1]."' ,'".$csv[$i][2]."')";
    mysql_query($sql);




 }
echo 'done';
?>
```